# Bifurcation diagram for 1D ising model

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm new in *Mathematica*, I want to plot a bifurcation diagram for a complicated Ising system with dynamics that I'm working on, but to get familiar with how to perform it on *Mathematica* I wish to start with well known mean field approximation

$$m = c\tanh(m)$$

I have no idea how to approach it, what I have so far is:

```
f1[c_, m_] := c Tanh[m];
f2[m_] := m;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your definitions, I assume you want to solve the equation $m = c\tanh(m)$ for $m$ as a function of the parameter $c$. Here is one way of doing this:

```
mMax = 100;
f1[c_, m_] := c Tanh[m];
f2[m_] := m;    
mIsing[sign_][c_] := 
 Module[{m}, 
  m /. Quiet[NSolve[f1[c, m] == f2[m] && -mMax < m < mMax, m]][[sign]]]

Plot[{mIsing[1][c], mIsing[-1][c]}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

[image: bifurcation]

The function `mIsing` has `c` as a variable and also depends on the parameter `sign` that can be $\pm 1$ for the upper and lower branch (if they exist). The main part id the numerical solution of the equation in `NSolve`.

I enclose the solver in a `Module` to make sure the variable `m` we're solving for is properly localized. The `Quiet` is in there to suppress a harmless warning message from the solver. Below the bifurcation, the two solutions are just identical to `0`.

A faster way to make the plot (*if* you only want a plot) is this:

```
ContourPlot[f1[c, m] == f2[m], {c, 0, 10}, {m, -10, 10}]
```

[image: bifurc2]

Comment: Actually, `zero` is a solution for all values of `c` as shown in the `ContourPlot`; your approach with `Plot` leaves off the third solution. Recommend generating data and using `ListLinePlot` to show all three solutions.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, I assumed we only want the nonzero solutions after the bifurcation - this illustrates how to select particular branches if desired. That depends on the goal of the question, which is left open...

Comment: @Jens ,thanks , this detailed solution was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

This really adds nothing to Jens answer (which I have upvoted). I just post it for fun (and to illustrate utility of `MeshShading`).

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{Show[
    Plot[p Tanh[x], {x, -10, 10}, MeshFunctions -> (# - p Tanh[#] &), 
     Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, 
     MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}], 
    Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> 300],
   ContourPlot[x == r Tanh[x], {r, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, GridLines -> {{p}, None}, 
    MeshFunctions -> (#1 &), Mesh -> {{p}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
   }], {p, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever. Wonder whether these can be saved as apps for the IPAD....pretty sure these visuals will encourage more students to take maths & physics.

Comment: @thils thank you...Mathematica is a wonderful tool to aid understanding...cannot answer iPad question...not enough fun and play in teaching and learning...MSE has taught me a lot so l like to share fun...sometimes I am over the top...so thank you for kind words :-)

Comment: reason I mention IPAD is bcos the schools want students to get one so it is easier to test students for several subjects...

Comment: @ubpdqn ,thanks , will work with what you did